# Applying a custom 1 square mile grid

Tags: grids-graticules

In ArcMap 10.3 I need to overlay a grid on my data sets where each cell is 1 square mile. I do not need the fishnet using geographic coordinates, just simply a grid of 1 square mile placed over the shapefiles and rasters being used.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with this important detail.

Comment: Are your data sets using a meter-based projected coordinate reference system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need the geographic coordinates of your fishnet but you would still use the fishnet tool to accomplish this.  Start the tool and for the cell width and height you should set it to 1609.34 meters. There are several other options available so below is the helpfile for fishnet.

http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00170000002q000000

Comment: If the OP's other data is in meters, he should use meters in this tool, so 1000.

Comment: Good catch, you are correct! (I corrected it in the answer)

Comment: Ack, I guess we need to see if his data is feet- or meter-based!

Comment: The data sets are meter based. This should work fine. It's almost always easy once someone else points out the answer. Thanks guys